# unable to switch to wpa from AP after powercycle

Tags: linux, debian, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am using Jessie (Raspberry Pi) and after boot it goes to AP mode. Then in python code I run these commands to switch it to WPA client mode:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking stop
sudo systemctl stop wpa_supplicant.service
sudo systemctl stop hostapd.service
sudo systemctl stop udhcpd.service
sudo systemctl start wpa_supplicant.service
sudo /etc/init.d/networking start
sudo wpa_action wlan0 stop
sudo /etc/network/if-down.d/resolvconf
sudo /etc/network/if-down.d/upstart
sudo /etc/network/if-down.d/wpasupplicant
sudo dhclient -v -r -pf /run/dhclient.wlan0.pid -lf /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.wlan0.leases wlan0
sudo ip link set dev wlan0 down
sudo /etc/network/if-post-down.d/avahi-daemon
sudo /etc/network/if-post-down.d/hostapd
sudo /etc/network/if-post-down.d/wireless-tools
sudo /etc/network/if-post-down.d/wpasupplicant
sudo wpa_action wlan0 stop
sudo ifup wlan0
```

If it sometimes connects to my Wifi, then I powercycle RPi for more than 5 minutes, next time I boot it is not able to connect to my Wifi again (when python with these commands run).

What am I doing wrong?